# Unable to connect TI SensorTag CC2650STK to IoT Foundation / Bluemix via Android App

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, iot, texas-instruments

I can connect the SensorTag with the BLE SensorTag app on my Android phone and I can use the default Push to Cloud Quickstart setup to send data to IoT Foundation Quickstart. But I fail when trying to connect to IoT Foundation as a registered device.

I have registered the device on IoT foundation.

I have the newest app from the Google Play Store (Android) and get an error while connecting ("Keine Berechtigung für Verbindung" ~ "No authorization for connection").

My configuration is:

```
Cloud Service: IBM IoT Foundation
Username:      use-token-auth
Password:      << Auth-token >>
Device id:     d:<<orgID>>:sensortag:<<device ID>>
Broker add.:   tcp://<<orgID>>.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com
Broker Port:   1883
Publish topic: iot-2/evt/sensors/fmt/json
```

I would appreciate any help on this.

PS: I know the same question was asked by Harald Uebele some time ago, but my error was not explained and my post there was deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TI Sensor android app does not yet support registered device connection to IOTF. That update is in the process but not publicly available yet.

Registered device connection does work currently with iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, you have "use-token-auth" - is that a typo? it should be "user-token-auth".

Perhaps try the following topic: iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json

Also, is your json payload wrapped in a "d" structure? E.g

```
{"d": {"temperature":32.5}}
```

It may be worth using an MQTT test client like MQTTlens (from Chrome web store). You can enter those details in so you can at least rule out its not the client.